# How can I change between arrow down and arrow up in a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, arrows

How can I show arrow up symbol in a button? Respectively, I would like it to change when clicked to arrow down. How can I do that??

I tried this but ....

```
<button onclick="sortTable(1)" id="up_down" type="button" class="button button2">Sort table<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort-asc"></i></button>
```

Comment: can you show us your `sortTable` function?

Comment: Why is it relevant? I just need a button that changes arrows when I press it.. The sorting works , but the button is outside the table.

Comment: because we would probably include it on `sortTable`.

Comment: instead of creating multiple functions - you might as well toggle it, inside your `sortTable`

Comment: all you need to do is `toggleClass` on your font-awesome, if you have jQuery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821948/how-to-sort-html-name-table-with-javascript
Here is the sorting made..

Comment: @Stender how can i toggleClass in this particular case?

Comment: not a button, but you can style it as you wish, take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078841/9615185

Answer (score 0):

I am using the latest font awesome documentation, I could not see `fa-sort-asc` so instead I use `fa-sort-up`.

```
function sortTable() {
  const ascending = false; // change the value to your sorting method to check if it's ascending or descending.
  const i = document.getElementById("up_down").getElementsByTagName("i")[0]
  i.classList.remove("fa-sort-up", "fa-sort-down");
  if (ascending) {
    i.classList.add('fa-sort-up');
    return;
  }

  i.classList.add('fa-sort-down');
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k6bxyps3/